# Distribute a population size based on fractions using random number generator drand48()

Tags: probability, random, uniform-distribution

I have a population size of say 5000 people. Every person belongs to either A, B, C or D category. I want to split the population as per a given fraction provided by user. for example, 99% of A, 0.4% of B, 0.3% of C and 0.3% of D ( total = 100% ). I just want to confirm whether my approach for this solution is correct or not. I use random numbers to do this. 
let,

```
fa = fraction of A, fb = fraction of B, fc = fraction of C and fd = fraction of D.
```

my algorithm is as follows: I write a function :-->

```
 function( returns a category type A,B,C or D)
 {
   double r = drand48();  // gives me random number between 0 and 1.0 (uniform dist)
   if( r < fa )
      return A;
   if( fa < r < (fa+fb) )
      return B;
   if( (fa+fb) < r < (fa+fb+fc) )
      return C;
   if( (fa+fb+fc) < r < (fa+fb+fc+fd) )
      return D;
 }
```

I just want to make sure, the population is distributed correctly as per the given fraction of each type provided.

I am not sure what category to tag this is.(sorry for the trouble)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle your code is right, except that there is a minuscle probability that `r` might equal e.g. `fa+fb` exactly, in which case none of the `if`s triggers.
You can drop the `<r` part of the condition (if repeated comparison is valid in your programming language of choice at all) anyway.
If it is given that `fa+fb+fc+fd` equals 1, you can also just `return D` if the third `if` fails.
So much for potential coding problems.

For the distribution, you are aware that the resulting population will not be distributed completely according to the given proportions, but rather like a *sample* from an infinite population where the proportions are valid? For example with $5000$ as size and $0.003$ for `D`, the actual number of `D`s produced need not be $15$, but can easily turn out as e.g. $11$ or $19$.

Comment: yes, i observed that in my code. I wont get exact population size as such.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm will give the distribution *on average*, it doesn't guarantee the distribution. I *guess* the following is enough: Set $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ to the number of elements in each category. Generate a random number $x$ uniformly between 0 and 1. Now, if $x \le a / (a + b + c + d)$, add the element to group $A$ and decrease $a$ by one; and do the same for the other groups. This ensures that a group that is full won't get more members. My random-fu isn't up to proving that this will select a distribution uniformly, however.

Comment: It will do it uniformly, perhaps easiest to see if you had as $5000$ categories with one member each. When you say "do the same for the other groups" you mean add to $B$ if $\dfrac{a}{a+b+c+d} \lt x \le \dfrac{a+b}{a+b+c+d}$ and then decrease $b$ by $1$ etc.